# Can i use Webview for Chatting in iPhone

Tags: iphone, webview

I am developing iPhone application for Chatting, I need to display the Chat message with font styles.
I have decided to use webview to every tableview cell. Message can be cross more than 1000, will it make memory issue or any other issue?

Thanks
Vadivelu

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `UITableView` you should always be sure to reuse table view cells by using the `dequeue` method. If you do this, you shouldn't have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You should use one single web view, and not use a table view at all.